How to access inbuilt sitecore publishing dialog when sitecore publishing service is configured for application
In my application, SPS is configured, when I click on the publish item, it opens up the publishing service dashboard.
But now I want to access the inbuilt default PublishDialog and user that service to publish items.
I want to keep both publishing options in the application.
Is there any way I can access the built-in publishing option where SPS is configured for the application?

The Sitecore Publishing Service (SPS) is an optional service that provides an alternative to Sitecore's default publishing process. It focuses on improving performance by performing operations in bulk. While it's not a direct replacement, SPS offers a different approach with variations in UI, integration points, deployment, and sometimes publishing behavior.
It is not possible to switch between both of them on the same Sitecore instance but yes You can switch between the default publishing method and SPS by enabling or disabling specific configuration files.
Here are some articles that you may refer to revert back to the default publishing service.
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0154093
https://sitecorecompetencies.com/2020/09/16/revert-to-default-publishing-from-publishing-service/
Hope this makes sense.

As far as I know this is not possible, because the standard publishing dialogue and the SPS dialogue use two completely different approaches to publishing:

Standard publishing triggers a job and waits for this job to be finished while showing a loading indicator to the user
SPS just puts a job in the publishing queue and lets the separate publishing service do the job, so the dialogue does not know when the job is finished.

To monitor the status of SPS jobs Sitecore provides a publishing dashboard with a list of active and queued publishing operations.
